# attr_accessor vs attr_reader & instance variables

Tags: ruby

could anyone please tell me the difference (if there are any) between

```
class Car
  attr_accessor :engine
  def initialize(engine)
    self.engine = engine
  end
end
```

and

```
class Car
  attr_reader :engine
  def initialize(engine)
    @engine = engine
  end
end
```

Or are they practically the same?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`attr_accessor`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) defines `getter` and `setter`.[`attr_reader`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader) defines only `getter`.

```
class Car
  attr_reader :engine
  def initialize(engine)
    @engine = engine
  end
end

Car.instance_methods(false) # => [:engine]
```

With the above code you defined only `def engine; @engine ;end`.

```
class Car
  attr_accessor :engine
  def initialize(engine)
    self.engine = engine
  end
end

Car.instance_methods(false) # => [:engine, :engine=]
```

With the above code you defined only `def engine; @engine ;end` and `def engine=(engine) ;@engine = engine ;end`.

Answer (score 7):

**attr_accessor :engine** allows you to read AND write to the variable @engine.

**attr_reader :engine** only allows you to read the value of @engine

**self.engine = engine** and **@engine = engine** pretty much do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

They are **NOT** the same.

To explain it in code

```
car = Car.new('cool engine')
```

##### For attr reader, you can only read

```
car.engine 
# cool engine
```

but you can't do

```
car.engine = 'even cool engine'
```

##### For attr_accessor, you can do both read and write

```
car.engine
# cool engine
car.engine = 'even cool engine'
car.engine
# even cool engine
```

##### For instance variables

Use only instance variables if you don't want to expose them to the outside world

```
class Car
  # You don't need to use attr_reader and attr_accessor here if you don't want to expose them to outside world
  def initialize(engine)
    @engine = engine
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same.

In the first example, you defined a method `engine=` and you call that method inside `initialize`. This would, for example, allow a subclass of `Car` to override the `engine=` to do something specific, and when you then call `initialize`, the method call would be dispatched to *that* overridden method. This allows subclasses to extend the behavior of `Car` without having to know about its internal representation.